# Can primary keys themselves contain duplicates but have unique rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

Eg, take this **ACCOUNT** table:

```
|num |   type  |amount|
|----------------------
| 1  |  cheque | 300  |
| 2  |  cheque | 300  |
| 2  | savings | 300  |
```

Would **[type, amount]** by a primary key even though **[cheque, 300]** appears twice?

I'm confused because even though cheque 300 is duplicated, the **num** column is different for the two duplicates, which means it still is part of a unique row.

Comment: No.  The primary key needs to be a unique combination of the values in the columns used for the key.  In general, I think it is good idea to have an auto-incremented numeric primary key on a table, which this table doesn't have.  In this case, you could define a unique or primary key on all three columns.

Comment: No, it isn't a primary key.

Comment: No.Primary Key is always UNIQUE & can not contain NULL values also.

Comment: after primary key added in ur table u can differentiate btw cheque by some person id or something there must be a relationship you are missing something in your table important like on what bases you are inserting values in your table

Comment: Yes, it could have been a PK provided `[num,type, amount]` is making the PK but in this case no; cause it's not unique at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [type, amount] cannot be primary key, because it is not unique.

There are two ways to work with primary keys in a database:

1. Work with technical IDs. You simply add an ID column to your tables and only link by these.
2. Work with natural keys. That would be the ISBN for a table of books for instance or the employee number in an employees table. Here you ask the question: "What makes a record unique in this table?". In your table this might be [num, type].

Comment: Okay I see, well what about superkeys? Are they similar to primary keys in that they themselves cannot contain duplicates?

Comment: Well, super keys are just a step in order to find a primary key for your table. Say you have a table department with dept_no, dept_name, description, and size. Superkeys are combinations of columns that would uniqely identify a record: [dept_no, dept_name, description, size], [dept_no, dept_name, description], [dept_no, size], [dept_name, description], [dept_no, dept_name], ... There are many, [size] is non, for two departments can have the same size. Even [size, description] may apply for two departments having the same tasks to do... [to be continued]

Comment: Now you would look for super keys where you can't remove a column without losing uniqueness, the so-called candiate keys. Of [dept_no, dept_name, size] you can reomove size and still have the records uniquely identified for instance, so this is no candidate key. From all the super keys only two remain as candidate keys [dept_no] and [dept_name]. You can decide to use one of these as primary key for the table. You can also decide not to use these, but add a technical id instead and make this primary key. Anyhow, you should at least have unique constraints on dept_no and dept_name.

Answer (score 1):

If `num` is the primary key, then it cannot contain duplicates or NULL values. "Primary key" implies no duplication.

It's conceivable that you could have a composite primary key consisting of `(id, type)`. That might make sense in an application where a particular `id` could have both a checking and a savings account associated with it.

Then an attempt to insert another row with values `2 | savings` would fail because of the primary key constraint.

Answer (score 1):

As you've pointed out, `num` is different between the two rows. That means that `num` and `type` could make a composite primary key, or you could even use `num`, `type`, and `amount` (although if those three columns constitute your whole table, that would be pretty pointless).

But because `type` and `amount` have duplicated data, they could not be your primary key. It doesn't matter that `num` has unique data if it's not included in the key. It's the columns in the primary key that must be unique, not the data of the entire row.

You say you're confused because, when you include `num`, the row would still be unique. But that doesn't matter if `num` isn't included in your index. A primary key is an index that's meant to help the database engine quickly locate and look up each individual row in a table. It improves performance by storing only a small subset of data to be used for these lookups. If it could take into account every column in the table -- such as `num` in your example -- it would have no purpose. The database engine would simply be scanning the entire table instead of performing a lookup.